# How do I get the cloud foundry services usage

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have deployed some services in cloud foundry. I need to get the usage of all my services. I referred to [this document](http://%20https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/opsguide/accounting-report.html#service-usage).

I have tried to explore the above documentation in python . I tried the below program:

```
import sys
import json
import requests
import cf_api
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from getpass import getpass
def apps():
    cloud_controller_url = 'https://app-usage.run.pivotal.io/system_report/service_usages'
    username='user'
    password='pass'
    response=''
    print('-----apps-----')
    print('Authenticating with UAA...')
    cc = cf_api.new_cloud_controller(
    cloud_controller_url,
    client_id='cf',  # the ``cf`` command uses this client and the secret below
    client_secret='',
    username=username,
    password=password,
    )
    print('Login OK!')
    print('----------')

    print('Searching for applications...')
    req = cc.request('/system_report/service_usages')
    resources_list = cc.get_all_resources(req)
    f = open ("cfServices.json", "w")
    print(json.dumps(resources_list))
    f.write(json.dumps(resources_list))


apps()
```

I also tried to explore it in postman. I got 404 error.

I am expecting results. this is the sample expecting output which is provided in cloud foundry documentation:

```
 {
      "report_time": "2017-05-11 18:29:14 UTC",
      "monthly_service_reports": [
        {
          "service_name": "fake-service-0507f1fd-2340-49a6-9d43-a347a5f5f6be",
          "service_guid": "177dcfde-cd51-4058-bd86-b98015c295f5",
          "usages": [
            {
              "month": 1,
              "year": 2017,
              "duration_in_hours": 0,
              "average_instances": 0,
              "maximum_instances": 0
            },
            {
              "month": 2,
              "year": 2017,
              "duration_in_hours": 0,
              "average_instances": 0,
              "maximum_instances": 0
            },
            {
              "month": 3,
              "year": 2017,
              "duration_in_hours": 4.182222222222227,
              "average_instances": 0,
              "maximum_instances": 2
            },
            {
              "month": 4,
              "year": 2017,
              "duration_in_hours": 2176.962222222186,
              "average_instances": 3,
              "maximum_instances": 7
            },
            {
              "month": 5,
              "year": 2017,
              "duration_in_hours": 385.61388888888854,
              "average_instances": 1.5,
              "maximum_instances": 3
            }
          ],
          "plans": [
            {
              "usages": [
                {
                  "month": 1,
                  "year": 2017,
                  "duration_in_hours": 0,
                  "average_instances": 0,
                  "maximum_instances": 0
                },
                {
                  "month": 2,
                  "year": 2017,
                  "duration_in_hours": 0,
                  "average_instances": 0,
                  "maximum_instances": 0
                },
                {
                  "month": 3,
                  "year": 2017,
                  "duration_in_hours": 4.182222222222227,
                  "average_instances": 0,
                  "maximum_instances": 2
                },
                {
                  "month": 4,
                  "year": 2017,
                  "duration_in_hours": 1465.6388888888941,
                  "average_instances": 2,
                  "maximum_instances": 5
                },
                {
                  "month": 5,
                  "year": 2017,
                  "duration_in_hours": 385.61388888888854,
                  "average_instances": 1.5,
                  "maximum_instances": 3
                }
              ],
              "service_plan_name": "fake-plan",
              "service_plan_guid": "ac09f607-f4e5-4807-af16-e95856061bd7"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe this api is for PAS owner who deploy PCF dev, and the PCF web services might not allow you to view that kind of information as it doesnot asking for ORG information

But i have something for you ,

you can use this api for each service you are using for fetching some of the information you want

```
REQUEST: [2019-01-28T22:58:19+05:30]
GET /v2/services/c72eba27-c3f6-4ccb-b2fb-0a7e8ce0a25 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.run.pivotal.io
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
User-Agent: cf/6.37.0+a40009753.2018-05-25 (go1.9.6; amd64 windows)

RESPONSE: [2019-01-28T22:58:19+05:30]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1619
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2019 17:28:18 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 20000
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 19941
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1548699889
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 87b81068-f777-45a8-46ff-a116d449bd49::d4a02e66-208b-40c4-a9b7-c4afdcc9ffce
{
  "entity": {
    "active": true,
    "bindable": true,
    "bindings_retrievable": false,
    "description": "Fully managed MongoDB-as-a-Service",
    "documentation_url": null,
    "extra": "{\n  \"displayName\": \"mLab\",\n  \"imageUrl\": \"https://d3bql97l1ytoxn.cloudfront.net/app_resources/5819/thumbs_64/img2243331358186927838.png\",\n  \"longDescription\": \"mLab is a fully managed MongoDB Database-as-a-Service (DBaaS)\\nplatform that automates the operational aspects of running MongoDB in\\nthe cloud.\",\n  \"providerDisplayName\": \"mLab\",\n  \"documentationUrl\": \"http://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/mlab.html\",\n  \"supportUrl\": \"https://support.mlab.com/\"\n}",
    "info_url": null,
    "instances_retrievable": false,
    "label": "mlab",
    "long_description": null,
    "plan_updateable": false,
    "provider": null,
    "requires": null,
    "service_broker_guid": "bb6733db-3bdc-4d6d-c5a-63e9bbc1f4de",
    "service_broker_name": "appdirect",
    "service_plans_url": "/v2/services/c72eba27-c3f6-4cb-b2fb-0a74e8ce0a25/service_plans",
    "tags": [
      "Cloud Databases",
      "Developer Tools",
      "Web-based",
      "Data Store",
      "document",
      "Windows",
      "Security",
      "IT Management",
      "mongodb",
      "Mac"
    ],
    "unique_id": "6213a86a-ae52-11e3-ac06-22000a1dd446",
    "url": null,
    "version": null
  },
  "metadata": {
    "created_at": "2015-01-19T21:16:29Z",
    "guid": "c72eba27-c3f6-4ccb-b2fb-0a74e8ce0a25",
    "updated_at": "2018-11-26T21:50:43Z",
    "url": "/v2/services/c72eba27-c3f6-4ccb-b2fb-0a7e8ce0a25"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you